# kendoDropDownListWithTooltip custom knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-tooltip

I want to create a custom binding to merge Kendo DropDownList and Kendo Tooltip. So I made this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoDropDownListWithTooltip =
  {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var local = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    // INIT DropDown
    ko.bindingHandlers.kendoDropDownList.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    var combo = $(element).data().kendoDropDownList;

    // INIT Tooltip
    if (combo) {
      var tooltipConfig = local.tooltip;
      var newValueAccessor = function () { return tooltipConfig; };
      ko.bindingHandlers.kendoTooltip.init(combo.wrapper, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work as expected.
I need to display tooltip when DropDownList is focused only. When Dropdown is not focused, tooltip must be hidden.

```
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownListWithTooltip: { data: choices, value: selectedChoice, tooltip: { showOn: 'focus', position: 'right', content: 'Tootlip Tooltip Tooltip' } }" />
```

[image]

But moving to other dropdows keeps all controls focused. Why and how to fix it?

https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/xXGPmK

**UPDATE**
Seems to be some bug in Kendo itself. Example without Knockout, just kendo controls. The same problem.
https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/RLPxZj

Comment: It seems that mousing over the selects when the tooltip is shown allows them to hide. Looks like buggy setup in the binding handler to me.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be some kind of bug in Kendo itself. Tried the same without Knockout and I've got the same result.